# How can I use JavaScript to select elements in GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

My goal is to check for an onClick event for the class "hamburger" in the navigation bar.

I have setup the component and styled accordingly however, I am unsure how to insert, and where to insert JavaScript to select this element and add an event listener.

Here is my current code:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import "../styles/master.scss"
import headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className={headerStyles.headerFlex}>
      <nav>
        <div className={headerStyles.hamburger}>
          <div className={headerStyles.line}></div>
          <div className={headerStyles.line}></div>
          <div className={headerStyles.line}></div>
        </div>
        <ul className={headerStyles.navLinks}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blog" activeClassName="active">
              blog
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">
              about
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/portfolio" activeClassName="active">
              portfolio
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact" activeClassName="active">
              contact
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: You should read about using ref in react
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

You can also use plain javascript to add event listeners, but that beats the purpose of react.

Comment: You can add event handler to an element not to a css class, just use onClick={handleClick} on the element

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review [Handling Events in the React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to learn about this. Here's an example of what your code might look like with this wired up:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import "../styles/master.scss"
import headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
  const someAction = () => {
    console.log("Clicked")
  }
  return (
    <header className={headerStyles.headerFlex}>
      <nav>
        <div className={headerStyles.hamburger} onClick={someAction}>
          <div className={headerStyles.line}></div>
          <div className={headerStyles.line}></div>
          <div className={headerStyles.line}></div>
        </div>
        <ul className={headerStyles.navLinks}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/blog" activeClassName="active">
              blog
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">
              about
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/portfolio" activeClassName="active">
              portfolio
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact" activeClassName="active">
              contact
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```